# 2 rows CSS layout with arbitrary number of element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I Have the following HTML structure:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>a1</a><p>p1</p></li>
    <li><a>a2</a><p>p2</p></li>
    <li><a>a3</a><p>p3</p></li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <li><a>ax</a><p>px</p></li>
</ul>
```

I sadly cannot modify the order, nor the structure.

My goal is to have :

- all the `<a>` flex'ed on a top row
- one or all the `<p>` in the rows **bellows**.

```
[a1 a2 a3 ... ax]
[      p1       ] // or any p
```

Is this even achievable ?

- I tried grid but the top row does not play well with flexing arbitrary column
- I tried flexbox but it does not play well with my 2 row goal

Comment: How would you have just one input? Would you hide or remove the others or will there just be the image tag? Could you use javascript or just CSS?

Comment: I have a css selector that's hide all but one input. Yeah no JS allowed, CSS only.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I got your questions right, but this css should come close to what you asked for. Not sure about how you exactly want the responsive behavior or how exactly you want the `input` fields to appear, but maybe it is a starting point for you.

To only show one input, I set the opacity of the `input`s to `0` and only the last one to `1`. Then I extended the width of this last one to 300% and gave it negative margin, which also must be adjusted for responsive behaviour.

So this is not an optimal solution yet, but it might direct you to where you want to go.

If you can clarify your question just comment my answere or edit your question and I can try to alter my answer.

```css
/*
Some resets for styling purpose
*/
ul,
li, 
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
/*
Reset end
*/
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}

p {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
li:last-child p {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  width: 300%;
  margin-left: -200%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>a1</a><p>p1</p></li>
    <li><a>a2</a><p>p2</p></li>
    <li><a>a3</a><p>p3</p></li>
    <!-- ... -->
    <li><a>ax</a><p>px</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the `width: 300%` and `margin-left: -200%` seems to be specific to the "3 columns" case.

I'll try to improve the question, thanks :)